# Why am I getting no connection on my Arch Wireguard peer?

Tags: networking, vpn, arch-linux, wireguard

I have had my PiVPN wireguard server up and running for over a year now with no issues. I add clients with "pivpn -a" and then copy their configuration to whichever device I am trying to connect with.

For some reason, I am completely unable to get my Arch laptop to successfully connect & get internet access through the VPN. I am thinking maybe there is some sort of bug in my iptables... although this is a nearly fresh installation of Arch and does not even have a firewall installed yet.

I have tried using a new config for the laptop... and I have also tried using another device's config which I know is working. Same results.

I am almost certain it is a problem on the CLIENT device, because all of my other devices are working fine & connecting as they should... with access to the local LAN devices and public internet.

After using "sudo wg-quick up home", here is what the Arch terminal says:

```
[#] ip link add home type wireguard
[#] wg setconf home /dev/fd/63
[#] ip -4 address add 10.6.0.4/24 dev home
[#] ip link set mtu 1420 up dev home
[#] resolvconf -a home -m 0 -x
[#] wg set home fwmark 51820
[#] ip -6 route add ::/0 dev home table 51820
[#] ip -6 rule add not fwmark 51820 table 51820
[#] ip -6 rule add table main suppress_prefixlength 0
[#] nft -f /dev/fd/63
[#] ip -4 route add 0.0.0.0/0 dev home table 51820
[#] ip -4 rule add not fwmark 51820 table 51820
[#] ip -4 rule add table main suppress_prefixlength 0
[#] sysctl -q net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
[#] nft -f /dev/fd/63
```

Here is the WG config I am connecting with:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = *private key that matches same key on server*
Address = 10.6.0.4/24
DNS = 10.6.0.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = *private key that matches same key on server*
PresharedKey = *redacted*
Endpoint = *redacted*:24454
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::0/0
```

I have tried running wg-quick as sudo and as regular user... no difference.
I am really stuck because I am not sure where I should really be looking to try to fix this. Like I said... this Wireguard server has been working for over a year now... It's very strange that I am having trouble with this one client which is even on a fairly fresh Arch install.

My last resort at this point is just reinstalling Arch... because I've never had this issue before and I have used the wg connection on other Arch installations before.

Any help is greatly appreciated, and I'll update this main post with any logs or anything you guys need to see.

Here is more iptables output:

```
# ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b0:3c:dc:6f:7b:56 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.20.20.20/24 brd 172.20.20.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft 3353sec preferred_lft 2903sec
    inet6 2601:586:d032:3ec:7933:1220:847c:2fd6/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 3347sec preferred_lft 1547sec
    inet6 fe80::743a:4f6c:81e2:f365/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:14:6e:67:d5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: br-f046ca5e5c8d: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:74:37:ca:f5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.19.0.1/16 brd 172.19.255.255 scope global br-f046ca5e5c8d
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:74ff:fe37:caf5/64 scope link proto kernel_ll 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: veth7f1f937@if6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-f046ca5e5c8d state UP group default 
    link/ether d2:10:6b:28:65:96 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::c0ac:691c:559f:9018/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

# ip -4 route show table all
default via 172.20.20.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 172.20.20.20 metric 3003 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-f046ca5e5c8d proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 
172.20.20.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 172.20.20.20 metric 3003 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo table local proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 
local 172.17.0.1 dev docker0 table local proto kernel scope host src 172.17.0.1 
broadcast 172.17.255.255 dev docker0 table local proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
local 172.19.0.1 dev br-f046ca5e5c8d table local proto kernel scope host src 172.19.0.1 
broadcast 172.19.255.255 dev br-f046ca5e5c8d table local proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 
local 172.20.20.20 dev wlan0 table local proto kernel scope host src 172.20.20.20 
broadcast 172.20.20.255 dev wlan0 table local proto kernel scope link src 172.20.20.20 

# ip -4 rule show
0:  from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

# ip -6 route show table all
2601:586:d032:3ec::/64 via fe80::ff:fe02:202 dev wlan0 proto ra metric 3003 mtu 1280 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev br-f046ca5e5c8d proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev veth7f1f937 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev wlan0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default via fe80::ff:fe02:202 dev wlan0 proto ra metric 3003 mtu 1280 pref medium
local ::1 dev lo table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local 2601:586:d032:3ec:7933:1220:847c:2fd6 dev wlan0 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local fe80::42:74ff:fe37:caf5 dev br-f046ca5e5c8d table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local fe80::743a:4f6c:81e2:f365 dev wlan0 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local fe80::c0ac:691c:559f:9018 dev veth7f1f937 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
multicast ff00::/8 dev br-f046ca5e5c8d table local proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
multicast ff00::/8 dev veth7f1f937 table local proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
multicast ff00::/8 dev wlan0 table local proto kernel metric 256 pref medium

# ip -6 rule show
0:  from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main

# wg

# ip netconf
inet lo forwarding on rp_filter loose mc_forwarding off proxy_neigh off ignore_routes_with_linkdown off 
inet wlan0 forwarding on rp_filter loose mc_forwarding off proxy_neigh off ignore_routes_with_linkdown off 
inet docker0 forwarding on rp_filter loose mc_forwarding off proxy_neigh off ignore_routes_with_linkdown off 
inet br-f046ca5e5c8d forwarding on rp_filter loose mc_forwarding off proxy_neigh off ignore_routes_with_linkdown off 
inet veth7f1f937 forwarding on rp_filter loose mc_forwarding off proxy_neigh off ignore_routes_with_linkdown off 
inet all forwarding on rp_filter off mc_forwarding off proxy_neigh off ignore_routes_with_linkdown off 
inet default forwarding on rp_filter loose mc_forwarding off proxy_neigh off ignore_routes_with_linkdown off 
inet6 lo forwarding off mc_forwarding off proxy_neigh off ignore_routes_with_linkdown off 
inet6 wlan0 forwarding off mc_forwarding off proxy_neigh off ignore_routes_with_linkdown off 
inet6 docker0 forwarding off mc_forwarding off proxy_neigh off ignore_routes_with_linkdown off 
inet6 br-f046ca5e5c8d forwarding off mc_forwarding off proxy_neigh off ignore_routes_with_linkdown off 
inet6 veth7f1f937 forwarding off mc_forwarding off proxy_neigh off ignore_routes_with_linkdown off 
inet6 all forwarding off mc_forwarding off proxy_neigh off ignore_routes_with_linkdown off 
inet6 default forwarding off mc_forwarding off proxy_neigh off ignore_routes_with_linkdown off 

# iptables-save -c
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.9 on Fri Sep  8 11:20:09 2023
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [80:10293]
:INPUT ACCEPT [74:8365]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [961:75284]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [961:75284]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
[74:8365] -A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
[0:0] -A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.0/16 ! -o br-f046ca5e5c8d -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 172.19.0.2/32 -d 172.19.0.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5432 -j MASQUERADE
[0:0] -A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
[0:0] -A DOCKER -i br-f046ca5e5c8d -j RETURN
[0:0] -A DOCKER ! -i br-f046ca5e5c8d -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5432 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.19.0.2:5432
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Sep  8 11:20:09 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.9 on Fri Sep  8 11:20:09 2023
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [10231:6567188]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [8540:1276935]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
[0:0] -A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
[0:0] -A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-f046ca5e5c8d -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -o br-f046ca5e5c8d -j DOCKER
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-f046ca5e5c8d ! -o br-f046ca5e5c8d -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i br-f046ca5e5c8d -o br-f046ca5e5c8d -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.2/32 ! -i br-f046ca5e5c8d -o br-f046ca5e5c8d -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-f046ca5e5c8d ! -o br-f046ca5e5c8d -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-f046ca5e5c8d -j DROP
[0:0] -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
[0:0] -A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Fri Sep  8 11:20:09 2023

# nft list ruleset
```